# How to get the Monday position of a month in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For example consider the April 2023. In this year the Monday dates are 3, 10, 17, and 24. Now I want to get the date 10 position of April.

My target result is: April 10 = second or 2

Comment: `(day(d) - 1) / 7 + 1`?..

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't understand the question.  Are you asking how to get for any given date how many Mondays have already occurred in that month?

Comment: No, not like that. I just need nth position. Like I will give '2023-04-10', and want the output = 2 or second. April 10 is the second Monday of 2023.

Comment: What do you expect if you pass in 2023-04-11?

Comment: I would suggest creating a [date dimension table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) If you need it in queries, the performance benefit of using a table vs using functions. If you add columns for the weekdays, you can use those in your query.

Comment: Please describe what you find, expect (with written examples instead of images) and if possible a formatted table with a few dates and what the results shall be. In addition please state which server locale you work on - it is really important for date manipulations.

Comment: @RashedulAlam So `(day('20230410') - 1) / 7 + 1` will give you `2`.

Comment: GSerg, thanks for your answer. It is working. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT (DAY('2023-04-10') - 1) / 7 + 1

Answer (score -1):

Position outputs the searched number for a date

```
WITH CTE_DATES 
AS(
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) -1, 0) AS DATE) AS [DATE] -- start previous month

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DD, 1, [DATE])  AS DATE)
    FROM [CTE_DATES]
    WHERE [DATE] < CAST(DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 0, 0)) AS DATE) -- end previous month
)

SELECT 
     [date] 
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [date]) AS 'Weekday'
    ,DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [date]) AS 'Day'
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date] ASC) AS 'POSITION'
FROM [CTE_DATES]
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [date]) IN (1)
```